# How to output only the last 5 double numbers from string in file(my code is wrong)

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

How to output last 5 double numbers from the string(in file)? I created an array to store those doubles there and then - print them as array. I've written it in function str_process. I think i do something wrong, because the code doesn't work and seems to be much smaller, isn't it? Thanks for attention.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<string.h>    
#include<ctype.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<progbase.h>    
#include<pbconsole.h>    

enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 100 };

int file_process(const char * readFileName, const char * writeFileName);
void str_process (const char * str);


int main(void){
 file_process("in.txt", "out.txt");
 return 0;
}          


/* prints last 5 float numbers of string */

void str_process (const char * str){

   /*FILE* fout = fopen("out.txt", "w"); */
  int count = 0;
  char * ptrEnd;

  while(str != '\0'){
    double d = strtod (str, &ptrEnd);   /* counts floats in string */
    count++;
  }

  double array[count];  

  if(count == 0) {
    fputs("No double numbers!", fout);
  }
  else {

    if(count < 5)
    {
     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        fprintf(fout, "%f ", array[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
      for(int i = count - 5; i < count; i++){
        fprintf(fout, "%f ", array[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}


int file_process(const char * readFileName, const char * writeFileName){

  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  FILE* fin = fopen(readFileName, "r");
  FILE* fout = fopen(writeFileName, "w");

  if (fin == NULL || fout == NULL){
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while(!feof(fin)){
    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fin);
    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
    str_process(buffer);
    fputs("\n", fout);
  }

  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The first loop is iterating over the same string over and over again...

Comment: Step 1: `double d = strtod (str, &ptrEnd);` --> `double d = strtod (str, &ptrEnd); str = ptrEnd;`

Comment: Recommend to avoid  "code doesn't work".  Instead post the input, observed results and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many, many issues with this code. You need to use the man pages *as* you're coding. For instance:

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fin);
buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
```

[The second line is redundant because of fgets man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

---

Going into your function, This is not the right way to use `strtod`, in addition you never actaully put anything inside your array:

```
while(str != '\0'){
    double d = strtod (str, &ptrEnd);   /* counts floats in string */
    count++;
}
double array[count]; // nothing is ever stored in here.
```

Vhange that loop to this:

```
double[500] doubles;
int i;
for (double d = strtod(str, &ptrEnd); str != ptrEnd; f = strtod(str, &ptrEnd))
{
    doubles[i] = d; // store doubles to array.
    i++;
}
```

This way, you now have all your doubles in one array.

---

Finally, you try to acces `fin` and `fout` even though they are not declared in the function you're using them. You need to declare them outside of the function, at the top of the file:

```
FILE* fin;
FILE* fout;
```

Stackoverflow is to help you issues only after you tried solving them yourself.